# ImageView vertical alignment - UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my issue:

I have an **UITableViewCell** with more than 1 line in the content (the text is very long).

The *vertical alignment* of the **ImageView** (I put an image in the left side of the cell) is in the centre (I guess this is by default), but I want to see this image in the top.

Do you have any idea of how can I modify its vertical alignment?

Any reply will be much appreciated.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I've subclasses UITableViewCell, and added this, which bumps it up to 10px below the top of the cell.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin.x = (60-self.imageView.frame.size.width)/2, .origin.y = 10, .size = self.imageView.frame.size};

}
```